# Why the Pop Up is being hidden instantly

Tags: jquery

I added this piece of code for preventing browser back button on a particular page

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    (function ($, global) {
        var _hash = "!",
        noBackPlease = function () {
            global.location.href += "#";

            setTimeout(function () {
                global.location.href += "!";
            }, 50);
        };

        global.setInterval(function () {
            if (global.location.hash != _hash) {
                global.location.hash = _hash;
            }
        }, 100);

        global.onload = function () {
            noBackPlease();

            // disables backspace on page except on input fields and textarea..
            $(document.body).keydown(function (e) {
                var elm = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                if (e.which == 8 && elm !== 'input' && elm  !== 'textarea') {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                // stopping event bubbling up the DOM tree..
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        }

    })(jQuery, window);

});
```

With the above code the Back Button functionality is working fine .

But the issue i am facing is that when i clicked on submit button the pop up is being hidden instantly

But when i remove the above code , everything si working fine

could you please tell me how to resolve this issue ??

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8uac7/2821/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this check is always not going to be equal

```
if (global.location.hash != _hash) {
```

`hash` is always going to return `#!` and `_hash` is `!`. So your backbutton code is not really working when there is a bug in it.

Second when the dialog opens, it sets the hash so it changes ad your back button code is going to wipe it out.

---

So change `var _hash = "#!",`

and

```
$('#vendoridpopupp').popup({
    history: false
  }).popup('open');
}
```

Comment: If you dont mind could you please let me know how to resolve this ??

Comment: well your _hash needs to include the `#` and your logic for the back button needs to account that the URL can change or you need to prevent it from updating.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the popup changes the [link](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html) and your interval see that it was changed and goes back to the original state (link) which has no popup active.

On jQuery [popup docs](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/options.html) i see that you can set history to false: 
`{ history: false }`